# Android custom Arrayadapter not showing data in list view

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want a page with highscores. I made a row.xml for the layout and I made a custom ArrayAdapter. When I print out my objects, I get the right info but it does not come into my list view. It shows nothing at all.

Here is my row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/txtNumber" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtName"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_gravity="top|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtScore"
        android:id="@+id/txtScore"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

My custom arrayAdapter

```
Package be.ehb.dt.multiscreen_highscores;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

// ** * Created by Naomi on 17/12/15. */

public  class PersonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

    public PersonAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Person> personen) {
        super(context,0, personen);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Person person = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }

        TextView txtNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
        TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        TextView txtScore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtScore);

        txtNumber.setText(""+person.number);
        txtName.setText(person.name);
        txtScore.setText(""+person.score);
    return convertView;
    }
}
```

And my mainActivity

```
package be.ehb.dt.multiscreen_highscores;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private ArrayList<Person> personen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Person> arrayOfPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        PersonAdapter adapter = new PersonAdapter(this,arrayOfPersons);
        ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listHighscores);


        personen=new ArrayList<>();
        personen.add(new Person(1,"Naomi",3454));
        personen.add(new Person(2,"Steven",2394));
        personen.add(new Person(3, "Lieven", 2254));
        Log.d("print",personen.get(1).toString());
        v.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Comment: `return personen.size()` in `getCount()` method.

Comment: use BaseAdapter instead when using POJO for dataholding

Comment: @YogeshSeralia Why ? Why can't use Array adapter?

Comment: @PiyushGupta I don't see where a getCount method is used? I am very new to android.

Comment: In adapter class. Its a override method. Just copy paste my code

Comment: you have  to add the data to person array first and than send it to adapter class ...by see your it seems  you sending empty array to your adapter that,s why it give empty view

Comment: @PiyushGupta for a newbie its good to use Parent Adapter in order to learn whole overriding methods that are used in child classes of BaseAdapter

Comment: @NaomiDeLeeuw Check my edited answer.. You have set empty arraylist in your adapter so also check my edit.

Comment: your arrayOfPersons is empty array. so, it is obvious that your listview is blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should modify your adapter code like ,

```
ArrayList<Person> personen;
public class PersonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

public PersonAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Person> personen) {
    super(context,0, personen);
    this.personen = personen;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return personen.size();
}
```

Now get here `Person person = personen.get(position);`

**Edit:**

```
    ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listHighscores);
    personen=new ArrayList<>();
    personen.add(new Person(1,"Naomi",3454));
    personen.add(new Person(2,"Steven",2394));
    personen.add(new Person(3, "Lieven", 2254));
    Log.d("print",personen.get(1).toString());
    PersonAdapter adapter = new PersonAdapter(this,personen)
    v.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: That's pointless. Take a look at the `ArrayAdapter#getCount()` method, it's already implemented like so: `return mObjects.size()` where `mObjects` is an array of objects you passed into your adapter.

Comment: @aga Where did you see that ?

Comment: @PiyushGupta I noticed my mistake thanks to your comment. I didn't use the ArrayList personen. I changed it to :

        `ArrayList<Person> arrayOfPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        PersonAdapter adapter = new PersonAdapter(this,arrayOfPersons);
        ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listHighscores);

        adapter.add(new Person(1, "Naomi", 3454));
        adapter.add(new Person(2,"Steven",2394));
        adapter.add(new Person(3, "Lieven", 2254));
        v.setAdapter(adapter);`